# My query isn't executed while there aren't any errors

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a login script in which I also execute a query to log when and from where people try to log in to my site. This little piece of code doesn't return any errors and the header works, but the query doesn't work for some reason. Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
if($count==1){

$securityquery = "INSERT INTO security_kk (action,datetime,country,IP,Affected table,comment) VALUES (:action,:datetime,:country,:IP,:Affected_table,:comment)";
$q = $db->prepare($securityquery);
$q->execute(array(':action'=>"Login",
                  ':datetime'=>$datetime,
                  ':country'=>$country,
                  ':IP'=>$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
                  ':Affected_table'=>"members",
                  ':comment'=>"Authenticated as ".$myusername));

$_SESSION['username'] = $myusername;
$_SESSION['privileges'] = $row['privileges'];
$_SESSION['email'] = $row['email'];
header("location:index.php");
}
```

I'm a beginner at PDO, but since there are no errors. I don't know where to look.

Comment: `Affected table` is that an actual column? If so, there's a space in it. You may have meant to use an underscore, and if not, wrap it in backticks `\``

Comment: Protip: `$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` Suddenly, errors! ;)

Comment: Mysql will certainly give you any error that happens. As allways, check your errors before searching for any bugs. In this case you might be getting the PHP errors, but not the PDO/MySQL errors!

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I'll turn on PDO/MySQL errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`datetime` is a data type in MySQL. Wrap that column identifier in ticks. Also, column identifiers with spaces in their name must be wrapped in ticks.

```
$securityquery = "INSERT INTO security_kk (`action`,`datetime`,`country`,`IP`,`Affected table`,`comment`) VALUES (:action,:datetime,:country,:IP,:Affected_table,:meta)";
```

Comment: It wouldn't hurt to add Affected table inside the quotes. Basically all can be added inside those quotes just to be on the safe side. Yep, cool +1

Comment: @AxelAmthor Yep. I noticed that while editing my question and added that to my answer.

Comment: Checking errors is the much more important solution thatn just fixing any errors you assume by going through the code blindly.

Comment: While it is true that `DATETIME` is a datatype in MySQL, it is also true that it is not actually a MySQL reserved word [http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/reserved-words.html](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/reserved-words.html) so it's not mandatory that it be escaped when it's used as an identifier. A column name that contains a space must be escaped (enclosed in backticks). And a much better coding practice is to check the return from the `prepare`, rather than a Dr.Evil-style pinky to the corner of the mouth, "I just assume it will all go to plan. What?"

Comment: @ToBe Agreed. Niet the Dark Absol addressed that issue in the comments.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Not surprised. This kind of question/problem tends to have multiple issues.

Answer (score 2):

Your error (or possibly one of the errors) is the difference between

```
:meta     // your query contains this
```

and

```
':comment'=>"Authenticated as ".$myusername;
```

Your array  has no value for the placeholder named `:meta`

It doesn't hurt to check for errors using the error checking functions though, rather than having others try to figure out a simple typo.

> while there aren't any errors

Because you aren't checking for them.

Comment: Hi, I had allready fixed this. Posted the old version in my question.

Answer (score 0):

1. DateTime is a datatype of mysql.
2. check your Affected table column name - No space in column name

best way to use like below.

```
$securityquery = "INSERT INTO security_kk (action,[datetime],country,IP,Affected table,comment) VALUES (:action,:datetime,:country,:IP,:Affected_table,:meta)";
```

Comment: **1(a)** DATETIME is *not* a reserved word in MySQL, so it's not necessary that it be escaped when used as an identifier. **1(b)** SQL server uses square brackets to escape identifiers, but MySQL doesn't. MySQL uses backtick characters, although double quotes can also be used if SQL_MODE contains ANSI_QUOTES. **2.** Best practice is to avoid using a space in an identifier, but it is valid. But an identifier that contains a space *must* be escaped in MySQL.